# Kafka Consumer Can't Receive Some Messages

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Recently,I had some problems when using kafka consumer AIPs,and there is my code:

```
public class ConsumerClientDemo {

    private static final String KAFKA_SERVERS = "17.162.110.1:9292,17.162.112.1:9293,17.162.114.1:9294";
    private static final String GROUP = "group-admin-test";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, KAFKA_SERVERS);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, GROUP);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "mbGW4rH5");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SASL_PLAINTEXT");
        props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, "PLAIN");

        props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, String.format(
                PlainLoginModule.class.getName() + " required username=\"%s\" " + "password=\"%s\";",
                "admin",
                "admin"
        ));
        final KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("mbGW4rH5"));
        final AtomicBoolean isShuttingDown = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            isShuttingDown.set(true);
            synchronized (consumer) {
                consumer.close();
            }
        }));
        try {
            while (!isShuttingDown.get()) {
                ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
                for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                        System.out.printf("topic=%s, partition=%s, offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s%n",
                                record.topic(), record.partition(),record.offset(), record.key(), deviceData.value());
                    }
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

It didnt have any problems at first,but when successfully received 15 messages,the console printed:

```
10:42:40:446 INFO [FetchSessionHandler] [Consumer clientId=mbGW4rH5, groupId=group-mbGW4rH5] Node 2 sent an invalid full fetch response with extra=(mbGW4rH5-0, response=(
10:43:10:499 INFO [FetchSessionHandler] [Consumer clientId=mbGW4rH5, groupId=group-admin-test] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=INVALID, epoch=INITIAL) to node 2: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to send request after 30000 ms..
```

and then the client was suspended since then,it couldn't receive any messages,so I turned up DEBUG of the log.and there are the logs:

```
10:58:11:200 INFO [FetchSessionHandler] [Consumer clientId=mbGW4rH5, groupId=group-mbGW4rH5] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=INVALID, epoch=INITIAL) to node 2: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to send request after 30000 ms..
10:58:11:200 DEBUG [Fetcher] [Consumer clientId=mbGW4rH5, groupId=group-mbGW4rH5] Added READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch request for partition mbGW4rH5-0 at offset 15 to node 17.162.114.1:9294 (id: 2 rack: null)
10:58:11:200 DEBUG [FetchSessionHandler$Builder] [Consumer clientId=mbGW4rH5, groupId=group-mbGW4rH5] Built full fetch (sessionId=INVALID, epoch=INITIAL) for node 2 with 1 partition(s).
10:58:11:200 DEBUG [Fetcher] [Consumer clientId=mbGW4rH5, groupId=group-mbGW4rH5] Sending READ_UNCOMMITTED FullFetchRequest(mbGW4rH5-0) to broker 17.162.114.1:9294 (id: 2 rack: null)
10:58:13:161 DEBUG [AbstractCoordinator] [Consumer clientId=mbGW4rH5, groupId=group-mbGW4rH5] Sending Heartbeat request to coordinator cloud-access.hanclouds.com:9292 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
10:58:13:207 DEBUG [AbstractCoordinator$HeartbeatResponseHandler] [Consumer clientId=mbGW4rH5, groupId=group-mbGW4rH5] Received successful Heartbeat response
10:58:15:113 DEBUG [ConsumerCoordinator] [Consumer clientId=mbGW4rH5, groupId=group-mbGW4rH5] Sending asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {mbGW4rH5-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15, metadata=''}}
10:58:15:159 DEBUG [ConsumerCoordinator$OffsetCommitResponseHandler] [Consumer clientId=mbGW4rH5, groupId=group-mbGW4rH5] Committed offset 15 for partition mbGW4rH5-0
10:58:15:159 DEBUG [ConsumerCoordinator$4] [Consumer clientId=mbGW4rH5, groupId=group-mbGW4rH5] Completed asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {mbGW4rH5-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15, metadata=''}}
10:58:16:162 DEBUG [AbstractCoordinator] [Consumer clientId=mbGW4rH5, groupId=group-mbGW4rH5] Sending Heartbeat request to coordinator 17.162.110.1:9292 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
10:58:16:217 DEBUG [AbstractCoordinator$HeartbeatResponseHandler] [Consumer clientId=mbGW4rH5, groupId=group-mbGW4rH5] Received successful Heartbeat response
10:58:19:162 DEBUG [AbstractCoordinator] [Consumer clientId=mbGW4rH5, groupId=group-mbGW4rH5] Sending Heartbeat request to coordinator 17.162.110.1:9292 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
10:58:19:211 DEBUG [AbstractCoordinator$HeartbeatResponseHandler] [Consumer clientId=mbGW4rH5, groupId=group-mbGW4rH5] Received successful Heartbeat response
10:58:20:114 DEBUG [ConsumerCoordinator] [Consumer clientId=mbGW4rH5, groupId=group-mbGW4rH5] Sending asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {mbGW4rH5-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15, metadata=''}}
10:58:20:165 DEBUG [ConsumerCoordinator$OffsetCommitResponseHandler] [Consumer clientId=mbGW4rH5, groupId=group-mbGW4rH5] Committed offset 15 for partition mbGW4rH5-0
10:58:20:165 DEBUG [ConsumerCoordinator$4] [Consumer clientId=mbGW4rH5, groupId=group-mbGW4rH5] Completed asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {mbGW4rH5-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15, metadata=''}}
10:58:22:163 DEBUG [AbstractCoordinator] [Consumer clientId=mbGW4rH5, groupId=group-mbGW4rH5] Sending Heartbeat request to coordinator 17.162.110.1:9292 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
10:58:22:226 DEBUG [AbstractCoordinator$HeartbeatResponseHandler] [Consumer clientId=mbGW4rH5, groupId=group-mbGW4rH5] Received successful Heartbeat response
```

It seemed that the client couldn't receive the offset of 15,So I changed the group,and set the offset to the latest and it worked again.So I want to ask why the offset of 15 can't be received? and how to jump over the offset which cant not be received to avoid the client being hanged? By the way the Kafka version was 2.0.0 and so was the kafka-clients.

Thanks.

Comment: How many brokers do you have? What's the topic replication?

Comment: 3 brokers and 1 replication

Comment: Maybe a broker went down between requests? If you want the topic to highly available, perhaps you should try with 3 replicas

Comment: the strangest is that if I close the Kafka SASL,this situation will not happen...I will try 3 replicas to see what happen..

Comment: I tried with 3 replicas,and after 3 days,the problem happend again.Is there any chance that it was a bug of kafka 2.0.0?

Comment: Hard to say, but if it's reproducible, you can create a JIRA bug report for the Kafka project